# Managing files in TFS repository - what software to use?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2019

generic question about chow to manage files in Devops with TFS (for legacy reasons, import data from VSS).

I can download latest or historic versions via browser but cannot upload them. For uploading new changesets I was using a Visual Studio Express. I currently lost an option to do so - is there any other way than going licenced VS Pro to do so? Is there a free standalone app that can be used for uploading content to DevOps which is using TFS?

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score -1):

A colleague of mine pointed me towards this:

Visual Studio Team Explorer 2022
A free solution for non-developers to interact with Azure DevOps Server and Azure DevOps.